# Render Each pixel with a different environment map

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am using a code that calculates an environment map for each pixel on an image separately. Is it possible to implement a render with blender where each pixel is rendered with a different environment map?

So it would calculate each pixel with a new environment map then move to render the next pixel etc

Comment: I think I don't understand what the code does exactly. Could you please provide that code?
If a face (in an UV map) is bigger than a single pixel what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality for this in Blender. That's because there is no reason for it to exist. It would simply be useless. I imagine that would only generate a very noisy image. You could probably make a script, that animates the camera in a way it renders a single pixel at a time scanning a bigger image using lens shifting, but that would be extremely inefficient because you would have to write a file for each pixel.

Comment: render border can be used this way

Comment: That would be better.

Comment: Wait a moment... Would it be better? Can you add renders to a single image with render border?